# send text from one android device to another through wifi

Tags: android, text, android-wifi, message

I'm tryng to do an apk to use my company's wifi conection to comunicate betwen us but I don't know how to conect with the other device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Adding Network Service Discovery (NSD) to your app allows your users
>   to identify other devices on the local network that support the
>   services your app requests. This is useful for a variety of
>   peer-to-peer applications such as file sharing or multi-player gaming.
>   Android's NSD APIs simplify the effort required for you to implement
>   such features.

https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html